# Excel ActiveX combobox displays selected date as number rather than date

Tags: excel, vba

I have an ActiveX combobox. Its ListFillRange is a range on another sheet. It finds the dates, but when I select them I get this weird value. Anybody know whats up and how to fix it?

I have tried fixing it through VBA code but its the same problem, I would really appreciate it.

Example code:

```
Private Sub ProdDateCombobox_DropButtonClick()
ProdDateCombobox.ListFillRange = "ProductionList"
End Sub
```

ProductionList being a range of cells D2;D100 with dates

Comment: See [ask], especially where it discusses providing a [mcve]. Basically: show; don't tell.

Comment: but how can i show when i can't post images? :P

Comment: What weird value? What code? What is to be fixed?

Comment: @Linexxlol it is unlikely you should be posting images. [Edit] and format the question and put the relevant code that reproduces or illustrates your problem in the body of the question. Don't post images of code or error messages, as this is textual information that should easy to copy and search.

Comment: I have an activex combobox. Its job is to show dates that it gets from another sheet, like "13-03-2018". So it shows these dates no problem, BUT. When i SELECT them in the combobox dropdown menu, they change to some weird value like 43124. I have edited my original post with code

Comment: @Linexxlol [Edit] your question and put details like this in the question. Comments can be deleted and questions should contain everything necessary to understand the problem posed. SO is not a thread forum. It is a question-and-answer model, where the idea is that good questions not only help you, but help others in the future.

Comment: @Linexxlol there you go, you have 11 reputation now. Go ahead and attach the picture please as you promised

Comment: Excel (or office in general) stores dates in a numeric format. 43124 is actually the value representing the date of 2018-01-24. You can verify this by executing the following command in the direct window of the VBA editor: `print CDate(43124)`. You can also see this when you change the format of a date formatted column to a numeric format, then all dates should also change to these "weird values" ;)

Comment: You could format your source dates as text so they appear in your drop-down looking like dates rather than the number that @bassfader mentions.  Your linked cell will display the date as text as well, but you should still be able to calculate with it.

Comment: @bassfader Setting the cells to "text" instead of "date" fixed my problem, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

The number you're getting is the number of days since 1st January 1900 - this is how Excel stores dates.

**One solution to the problem is:**

You have your dates, formatted as dates, in the range `D2:D100` named as `ProductionList`.

When you select the drop-down the dates appear correctly in the drop-down, but the selected date appears as a number - 4th July 2018 showing the number 43285 (days since January 1st 1900).

- In a blank range enter the formula `=TEXT(D2,"dd/mm/yyyy")` where `D2` is the first date in your `ProductionList` named range.  Drag the formula down to the end of the dates.
- Copy this new range of formula and *paste special* as *values* only over your original list.

Your original list should now show correctly in the combo-box, but you'll have problems when trying to compare dates to your linked cell.

For example, if your linked cell is `A5` the formula `=MATCH(DATE(2018,3,1),$A$5,0)` will return `#N/A`.

To solve this enter a formula in cell `B5`:  `=A5+0` and compare against this.  The act of adding 0 to your text date will force it to recalculate as a real date.

Comment: This partially fixes the problem, however i can't drag the formula down because all my other dates will be the same date as my original. I also can't paste special as values, only unicode text and text.

EDIT: @bassfader fixed my problem

Comment: Why can't you drag down?  `D2` will update as you drag down as it's a [relative reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9).  `Unicode text` & `text` make it sound like you're using a new instance of the Excel application rather than just entering the formula in a blank range next to your original range.