# Having weird bug with date format in excel

Tags: excel, vba

So i have an activeX combobox that shows dates in the format "dd-mm-yyyy". The dates are taken from a range on another sheet. I have a linked cell (lets say A1) in which the date from the combobox is displayed.

It works fine for most dates but for some reason on some dates like 10-09-2018 or 11-03-2018, it changes format in the linked cell to "mm-dd-yyyy".

Does it get confused about which of the first two values are day and month?

Edit: the cells in my range are all text, and my linked cell is Date, however it didn't work to change these on either my linkedcell or range.

Code for my combobox, E26 is the cell with  the problem, E29 is just a cell where i add 2 years to the date, it always shows the date correctly.

```
Private Sub ProdDateCombobox_Change()
Range("E26") = Format(Me.ProdDateCombobox.Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
Range("E29") = DateAdd("yyyy", 2, Me.ProdDateCombobox.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information maybe some screenshots etc?

Comment: Sure

[Correct Format]https://imgur.com/SWwPG4A 

[Incorrect Format]https://imgur.com/WreOKuR

It should always have same format as in the combobox

Comment: Ok thanks ill take a look

Comment: What are your windows regional short-date settings?  And how do the text dates get from your range to the combo box

Comment: On my other sheet i have a named range for my dates, "productionList" i put this in the ListFillRange property of the combobox. 

My regional short-date settings are set to Danish, which is on the format "dd-mm-yyyy" which is why i maybe think that it gets confused when it sees 12-11-2018, it doesn't know which one is month and day, because they could both be i guess?

Comment: Edit your original post to show the VBA code you are using to fill the combo box.  VBA is US centric, and it may be where the issue lies.

Comment: Think this link will add context [excel activex combobox displays selected date as number rather than date  / Super weird bug with excel activeX combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175177/excel-activex-combobox-displays-selected-date-as-number-rather-than-date/51176443#51176443)

Comment: Check if the `E26` number format is `mm-dd-yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it! its a bit of a "hack" but i simply replaced

```
Range("E26") = Format(Me.ProdDateCombobox.Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

With this:

```
Range("E29") = DateAdd("yyyy", 0, Me.ProdDateCombobox.Value)
```

Its weird and i don't know why it works but it works. Thanks for trying to help.